# Como retornar um objeto, calculando datas?

Tags: javascript

Estou a calcular a diferença entre datas em um período. De hoje até x dias anteriores:

```
hoje = new Date();
periodo = new Date().setDate(hoje.getDate() - 5);
```

Dessa forma a saída é a seguinte:

```
Fri Sep 19 2014 17:05:11 GMT-0300 (Local Standard Time)
1409861111749
```

Eu quero que a data calculada também volte como objeto:

```
Fri Sep 14 2014 17:05:11 GMT-0300 (Local Standard Time)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você pode criar uma nova data a partir do timestamp retornado pela operação de setDate:

```
periodo = new Date(new Date().setDate(hoje.getDate() - 5))
```

De acordo com a [especificação da linguagem](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.36), setDate sempre retorna um TimeClip, que representa o número de milisegundos desde 1o. de janeiro de 1970 (UTC) até a data em questão.